# Создание подзадач для основной задачи

Tags: javascript, html5

Возникла проблема. Я создаю приложение на js. В нем присутствует: добавление задачи, редактирование название, изменение приоритета и изменение цвета при выполнении . И вот какая сложность появилась. Как реализовать подзадачи основной задачи ? То есть жмакнуть на саму задачу(на скрине это work) и перейти в неё, а там уже добавлять подзадачи к ней + при выходе/перезагрузке страницы все должно оставаться без задействования базы данных (я использую память браузера). Переварить и сообразить не как не могу . Нужна помощь спецов.
[image: Внешнее оформление]

Код всего js (не самый лучший , пока учусь)

```js
const form = document.querySelector('form');
const ul = document.querySelector('tbody');
const input = document.getElementById('item');
const addItem = document.getElementById('addItem');
let itemsArray = localStorage.getItem('items') ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('items')) : [];


// ------------------- add tr ---------------------

const liMaker = (text) => {

    const li = document.createElement('tr');
    li.innerHTML = `
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="qwe">
    </td>
    <td class="name-list">
        <p class="p_input" id="Name"><a href="#">${text}</a></p>
    </td>
    <td class="editing-list">
        <div class="editing">
             <img src="images/UpDown.png" alt="UpDown" onclick="change(this)" class="trUp">
            <div class="vl"></div>
            <img src="images/pen.png" alt="editing" class="editing-name">
            <div class="vl"></div>
           <a href="#"><img src="images/basket.png" alt="basket" class="clear"></a>
        </div>
    </td>`;
    function clickListener(evt) {
        if (evt.target.className == "clear") {
            let tr = evt.currentTarget;
            tr.removeEventListener("click", clickListener);
            window.onunload = function (evt) {
                localStorage.setItem("items", JSON.stringify(itemsArray));
            }

            itemsArray.splice(itemsArray.indexOf(text), 1);
            tr.parentElement.removeChild(tr);
        }
    }
    li.addEventListener("click", clickListener)
    ul.appendChild(li);
    t3();
}

// ------------------- function ---------------------

form.addEventListener('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (itemsArray.includes(input.value)) {
        input.value = "";
        return;
    }
    itemsArray.push(input.value);
    liMaker(input.value);
    input.value = "";
});

itemsArray.forEach(item => {
    liMaker(item);

});

window.onunload = function (evt) {
    localStorage.setItem("items", JSON.stringify(itemsArray));
}


//  --------- checked -----------

function t3() {
    let k = document.querySelectorAll('.checkbox');
    let td = document.querySelectorAll('tr');
    for (var i = 0; i < k.length; i++) {
        k[i].onchange = function () {
            Array.from(k).map((v, i) => {
                if (v.checked) {
                    Array.from(td)[i].style.cssText = "background-color:green";
                }
                else {
                    Array.from(td)[i].style.cssText = "";
                }
            })
        }
    }
}

// ---------- change Name --------- 

document.addEventListener(`click`, e => {
    if (e.target.classList.contains(`editing-name`)) {
        let paragraph = e.target.parentElement.parentElement.previousElementSibling.firstElementChild;
        let x = document.createElement('input');
        x.classList.add('NameCh');
        paragraph.innerHTML = ' ';
        paragraph.append(x);
        x.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
            if (e.keyCode === 13) {
                paragraph.innerHTML = x.value;
            }
        });
    }
})

// ----------------- trUp -------------------
function change(i) {
    var tr1, tr2;
    if (!(tr1 = document.getElementsByTagName('tr')[0]) || !(tr2 = i.closest('tr')))
        return;
    tr2.parentNode.insertBefore(tr2, tr1);
}
```

```css
body{
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}
a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color:black;
}
.container {
   transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
   position: absolute; 
   top: 50%; 
   left: 50%;
    }
.notebook{
    width: 1000px;
    min-height: 400px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 0 0 20px 20px;
}
/* -------------------- header -------------------- */
.header{
    background: #4677b2;
    height: 70px;
}
.icon{
  float: left;
    width: 100px;
    height: 70px; 
}
.icon img{
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 10px 25px;
}
.icon a{
   text-align: center;
}
.name{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 760px;
    color: #fff;
}
.editing{
    display:block;
   
}
.editing img{
    width: 35px;
    height: 35px;
}
.editing p {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 5px;
}
.editing-header{
    display:inline-block;
    margin-top: 15px;
}
.editing-header img{
    width: 35px;
    height: 35px;
}
.editing-header p {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 5px;
}
/* -------------------- input -------------------- */
.input{
    height: 70px;
    background: goldenrod;
    background: #cfcfcf;
}
.input-note{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 870px;
}
.input-note input{
    margin-top: 12px;
}
.input-name{
    height: 40px;
    width: 700px;
    border: 1px solid #707070;
}
#button-input-value{
    float: right;
    width: 163.3px;
    margin-top: 12px;
    height: 44px;
    background: #76ad8e;
    border-radius: 0 10px 10px 0;
    border: 1px solid #707070;
}
/* -------------------- list -------------------- */
.list{
    height:auto;
}
.list-table{
    position: relative;
    width: 1000px;
    height: auto;
}
table{
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin: 5px;
}
.list-table table{
    margin-left: 7px;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border: 2px solid #fff;
    border-radius:0 0 20px 20px;
}

 td ,tr {
    padding: 0;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
td{
    height: 50px;
}
.checkbox{
    width: 80px;
}
.name-list{
    width: 710px;
}
.editing-list{
    width: 185px;
}
#qwe {
    transform:scale(1.3);
    cursor:pointer;
}
p{
    font-size: 18px;
    margin-left: 15px;
}
.vl {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 5px ;
    border-left: 1px solid black;
    height: 30px;
}

.editing{
    display:none;
}
tr:hover .editing{
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    margin-left:10px ;
    margin-top: -15px;
    z-index:9999;

}
.editing-name{
    cursor: pointer;
}
.nameInput{
    height: 20px;
    font-size: 16px;
}
form{
    display: inline-block;
}
.trUp{
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Notebook</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lato&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body>

<div class="container">
        <div class="notebook">
            <!-- ----------- header ----------- -->
            <div class="header">
                <div class="icon">
                    <a href="index.html"><img src="images/icon.png" alt="icon"></a>
                </div>
                <div class="name">
                    <h2>For home</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- ----------- input ----------- -->
            <div class="input">
                <div class="icon">
                    <img src=" images/plus.png" alt="icon" class="plus">
                </div>
                <form class="input-note">
                    <input type="text" class="input-name" id="item">
                    <button id="button-input-value" name="submit">Add Task</button>
                </form>
            </div>
            <!-- ----------- list ----------- -->
            <div class="list">
                <div class="list-table">
                    <table>
                        <tbody>

                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`itemsArray` - массив, где вы храните данные вида `["task-1", "task-2", "task-3"]`

Должен (как вариант) быть таким:

```
const itemsArray = [
  {
    text: "task-1",
    checked: true, // Галочка была отмечена? При создании tr покрасить зеленым
    sub: [ // Список подзадач
      { text: "task-1-1", checked: true },
      { text: "task-1-2", checked: false },
      { text: "task-1-3", checked: false },
    ]
  },
  {
    text: "task-2",
    checked: false,
    sub: [
      { text: "task-2-1", checked: true },
    ]
  },
];
```

И тогда, заменить в коде:

`if (itemsArray.includes(text)) { ...`

↓

```
let CURR_TASK_SPACE = itemsArray; // глобальный
/* Менять на соответствующий вложенный sub или обратно на itemsArray
 при входе-выходе из подзадач.
 Так, чтобы всегда ссылался на текущий массив отображаемых задач. */

// где-то внутри, отсеивая повторы...
if (task_exists(text)) { ...

function task_exists(text) {
  return CURR_TASK_SPACE.some(task => task.text === text);
}
```

Т.к. уровень вложенности всего один, не нужно запоминать родительский объект задач. И можно тупо обновить всю таблицу, заново циклом добавив все задачи из `CURR_TASK_SPACE` в виде новых tr. Да, не "оптимально", но и задач-то будет всего десяток-два.

В таком случае, нужна функция а-ля `create_table(data)` которая берет массив задач и всё пихает в таблицу в виде tr (которая будет вызываться один раз при получении данных из localStorage, и в дальнейшем, при переключениях к подзадачам и обратно).

А при клике на задачу, надо уметь находить её подзадачи. Т.к. названия задач уникальные, можно прочитать значение прямо из HTML:

```
function find_sub(tr) {
  if (режим_редакции) return;

  let paragraph = tr.querySelector(".параграф-с-текстом-задачи");
  return CURR_TASK_SPACE.find(task => task.text === paragraph.textContent);
  // Если уже находится в sub, или такой задачи по какой-то причине нет,
  // не будет ошибки, просто вернет undefined
  
  // Если sub найден, функция, которая вызвала find_sub(),
  // • выставит CURR_TASK_SPACE = sub;
  // • позовет create_table(sub);
}
```

---

`localStorage.setItem("...", JSON.stringify())` — вместо прямых обращений в коде, это можно завернуть в такие функции:

```
function get_data() {
  let data = localStorage.getItem("DATA");
  return data ? JSON.parse(data) : [];
}

function set_data(data) {
  localStorage.setItem(JSON.stringify(data));
}
```

Может захочется для тестов временно подсунуть другие данные, или заменить localStorage на что-то другое. Это удобнее делать, если всё происходит в одном месте.

P.s. Вообще-то `itemsArray` не очень хорошее название: Может случиться так, что массив в будущем превратится в другую структуру. А в коде уже везде разбросано слово "Array" )

P.s.s. Удаление, редакцию, поднятие вверх, краску при checked - это всё по хорошему нужно реализовать через делегирование событий, чтобы при вставке новых строк таблицы не думать про добавление и обработку событий.

```
tbody.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
  let target = e.target;
  let tr = target.closest("tr");

  if (!tr) return;

  if (target.matches(".класс-редакции")) return task_edit(tr);
  if (target.matches(".класс-всплытия")) return task_move_top(tr);
  if (target.matches(".класс-удаления")) return task_delete(tr);
});


function task_edit() { ... }

function task_delete() { ... }
```

UPD: Начал переписывать ваш код, пытаясь не трогать HTML и стили (добавил thead в таблицу и 3 новых стиля), в итоге от начального кода ничего не осталось) Но что-то рабочее - получилось организовать:

```js
let tbody = document.querySelector('tbody');

/*****/

let DATA = get_data(); // Получает основные данные из localStorage

let CURR_TASK_SPACE = DATA;
/* Изменяемая ссылка на массив: группу задач, с которой "сейчас" работаем.
 Функции таблицы (создание / удаление / редакция) оперируют его элементами
 Сейчас это основные задачи, позже может указывать на вложенный массив подзадач
 */

update_table(); // Рисует таблицу на основе CURR_TASK_SPACE

window.onunload = function () {
  set_data(DATA);
};

/***/
function get_data() {
  /* Объект для тестов, в реальном коде можно превратить в комментарий,
  чтобы иметь представление, с какими данными вообще работаем */

  return [
    {
      text: "task-1",
      checked: false,
      sub: [
        { text: "task-1-1", checked: true },
        { text: "task-1-2", checked: false },
        { text: "task-1-3", checked: false },
      ]
    },
    {
      text: "task-2",
      checked: true,
      sub: [
        { text: "task-2-1", checked: false },
      ]
    },
  ];


  let data = localStorage.getItem("DATA");
  return data ? JSON.parse(data) : [];
}

function set_data(data) {
  return; /* Заглушка */

  localStorage.setItem(JSON.stringify(data));
}

/***/

function update_table() {
  /* CURR_TASK_SPACE = [
    {
      text: "str",
      checked: Boolean,
    },
    ...
  ] */

  tbody.textContent = "";

  CURR_TASK_SPACE.forEach(item => {
    create_task(item.text, item.checked);
  });
}

function create_task(text, checked) {
  let tr = document.createElement('tr');

  /* ниже, id="qwe", id="Name" надо убрать или заменить на классы.
  id по определению должен быть уникальным на странице.
  Оставил, чтобы не сломать ваш CSS */

  tr.innerHTML = `
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="qwe" ${checked ? "checked" : ""}>
    </td>

    <td class="name-list">
      <p class="p_input" id="Name"><a href="#">${text}</a></p>
    </td>

    <td class="editing-list">
      <div class="editing">
        <img src="images/UpDown.png" alt="UpDown" class="trUp">
        <div class="vl"></div>

        <img src="images/pen.png" alt="editing" class="editing-name">
        <div class="vl"></div>

        <a href="#"><img src="images/basket.png" alt="basket" class="clear"></a>
      </div>
    </td>
  `;

  if (checked) tr.classList.add("done");
  // Вместо style.backgroundColor = "green"; добавил класс,
  // т.к. цвет меняется не только тут.
  // Чтобы при необходимости, редактировать только стили в одном месте.

  tbody.appendChild(tr);
}

/*****/
// С обработкой и отображением данных разобрались, теперь функционал

onsubmit_add_task();
task_user_features();
sub_task_features();

/***/
function get_task_data(tr, remove) {
  /* В массиве CURR_TASK_SPACE хранятся объекты задач
  всегда в том же порядке, что и текущие tr
  
  Берет tr, выдает соответствующий ему объект
 
  Если передали второй аргумент (опционально),
  заодно и удалит объект из хранилища */

  let index = [].indexOf.call(tr.parentNode.children, tr);
  // Номер полученного tr среди всех соседних.
  
  return remove ? CURR_TASK_SPACE.splice(index, 1)[0] : CURR_TASK_SPACE[index];

  // Справка: splice удаляет элемент из массива и возвращает
  // массив удаленных элементов, откуда достается [0]-й (как-раз удаленный) элемент
  // Т.е. функция всегда возвращает объект задачи по tr, что от неё и нужно
}

/***/
function onsubmit_add_task() {
  let form = document.querySelector('form');
  let input = document.getElementById('item');
  // Перенес объявление ближе к коду, где они используются.
  // Не обязательно вывалить все переменные одним блоком, прямо в самом начале.

  form.addEventListener('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    let text = input.value;
    input.value = "";

    if (task_exists(text)) return;

    create_task(text);

    CURR_TASK_SPACE.push({
      text: text,
      checked: false
    });
    // Создается и добавляется новый объект текущей задачи
    // Без списка подзадач sub: [], он будет добавлен по мере необходимости
  });

  /***/
  function task_exists(text) {
    // возвращает true, если найдет хотя бы один task с совпадающим текстом
    return CURR_TASK_SPACE.some(task => task.text === text);
  }
}

function task_user_features() {
  tbody.addEventListener("change", function (e) {
    if (e.target.matches(".checkbox")) {
      let tr = e.target.closest("tr");
      toggle_checked(tr, e.target.checked);
    }
  });

  tbody.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    let target = e.target;
    let tr = target.closest("tr");

    if (!tr) return;

    if (target.matches(".editing-name")) return task_edit_mode(tr);
    if (target.matches(".trUp")) return task_move_top(tr);
    if (target.matches(".clear")) return task_delete(tr);
  });


  /***/
  /* помимо изменений в HTML, также вносят изменения в CURR_TASK_SPACE */

  function task_edit_mode(tr) {
    let a = tr.querySelector(".p_input a");
    a.setAttribute("contentEditable", true);
    // Стили можно добавить на .p_input a[contentEditable] { border: 1px solid }

    a.addEventListener("keydown", function _tmp(e) {
      if (e.keyCode === 13) { // "Enter"
        a.removeAttribute("contentEditable");
        a.removeEventListener("keydown", _tmp);

        get_task_data(tr).text = a.textContent;
      }
    });
  }

  function task_move_top(tr) {
    tbody.insertAdjacentElement("afterBegin", tr);

    let data = get_task_data(tr, "remove"); // удаляет объект из середины
    CURR_TASK_SPACE.unshift(data); // пихает в начало
  }

  function task_delete(tr) {
    tr.parentNode.removeChild(tr);

    // вместо вызова get_task_data(tr, true);
    get_task_data(tr, "remove");

    // Строка "remove" в логическом контексте тоже true.
    // Зато понятно, чего хотим от функции, вместо абстрактного true
  }

  function toggle_checked(tr, checked) {
    /* Добавляет или удаляет класс "done" на tr, в зависимости от значения checked */

    tr.classList.toggle("done", checked);
    // checked == true ? добавится, иначе - удалится.

    get_task_data(tr).checked = checked;
  }
}

function sub_task_features() {
  let thead = document.querySelector("thead");

  entering_sub_task_mode();
  back_to_primary_tasks();

  /***/
  function entering_sub_task_mode() {
    let primary_task = document.querySelector("#selected-task-text");
    // При входе в режим подзадач, копировать сюда текст основной задачи

    tbody.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
      let task_name = e.target.closest("td.name-list");
      if (!task_name) return; // кликнули не на td с названием задачи

      if (thead.matches(".sub-task-mode")) return;
      // и так находимся в подзадачах, нет вложенных подзадач

      let edit_mode = task_name.querySelector("a[contentEditable]");
      if (edit_mode) return; // задачу редактируют


      /*** Входим в подзадачи */
      thead.classList.add("sub-task-mode");
      primary_task.textContent = task_name.textContent;

      let tr = task_name.parentNode;
      let data = get_task_data(tr);
      if (!data.sub) data.sub = []; // подзадачи еще не создавали, создает.

      CURR_TASK_SPACE = data.sub;
      // начинает ссылаться на массив подзадач

      update_table();
    });
  }

  function back_to_primary_tasks() {
    let back = document.querySelector("#back");

    back.addEventListener("click", function () {
      thead.classList.remove("sub-task-mode");

      CURR_TASK_SPACE = DATA;
      // снова начинает ссылаться на большой массив задач
      update_table();
    });
  }

}
```

```css
thead {
  display: none;
}

thead.sub-task-mode {
  display: table-row-group;
}

tr.done {
  background-color: green;
}

/* дальше - не трогал */

body {
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

.container {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
}

.notebook {
  width: 1000px;
  min-height: 400px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 0 0 20px 20px;
}

/* -------------------- header -------------------- */
.header {
  background: #4677b2;
  height: 70px;
}

.icon {
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  height: 70px;
}

.icon img {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 10px 25px;
}

.icon a {
  text-align: center;
}

.name {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 760px;
  color: #fff;
}

.editing {
  display: block;

}

.editing img {
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
}

.editing p {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5px;
}

.editing-header {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 15px;
}

.editing-header img {
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
}

.editing-header p {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5px;
}

/* -------------------- input -------------------- */
.input {
  height: 70px;
  background: goldenrod;
  background: #cfcfcf;
}

.input-note {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 870px;
}

.input-note input {
  margin-top: 12px;
}

.input-name {
  height: 40px;
  width: 700px;
  border: 1px solid #707070;
}

#button-input-value {
  float: right;
  width: 163.3px;
  margin-top: 12px;
  height: 44px;
  background: #76ad8e;
  border-radius: 0 10px 10px 0;
  border: 1px solid #707070;
}

/* -------------------- list -------------------- */
.list {
  height: auto;
}

.list-table {
  position: relative;
  width: 1000px;
  height: auto;
}

table {
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: 5px;
}

.list-table table {
  margin-left: 7px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 0 0 20px 20px;
}

td,
tr {
  padding: 0;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

td {
  height: 50px;
}

.checkbox {
  width: 80px;
}

.name-list {
  width: 710px;
}

.editing-list {
  width: 185px;
}

#qwe {
  transform: scale(1.3);
  cursor: pointer;
}

p {
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-left: 15px;
}

.vl {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 5px;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  height: 30px;
}

.editing {
  display: none;
}

tr:hover .editing {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-top: -15px;
  z-index: 9999;

}

.editing-name {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.nameInput {
  height: 20px;
  font-size: 16px;
}

form {
  display: inline-block;
}

.trUp {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lato&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="container">
  <div class="notebook">
    <!-- ----------- header ----------- -->
    <div class="header">
      <div class="icon">
        <a href="index.html"><img src="images/icon.png" alt="icon"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="name">
        <h2>For home</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- ----------- input ----------- -->
    <div class="input">
      <div class="icon">
        <img src=" images/plus.png" alt="icon" class="plus">
      </div>
      <form class="input-note">
        <input type="text" class="input-name" id="item">
        <button id="button-input-value" name="submit">Add Task</button>
      </form>
    </div>
    <!-- ----------- list ----------- -->
    <div class="list">
      <div class="list-table">
      
        <table>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th id="back">←</th>
              <th colspan="2" id="selected-task-text"></th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          
          <tbody></tbody>
        </table>
        
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Разъясните подробнее : /* Менять на соответствующий вложенный sub или обратно на itemsArray
 при входе-выходе из подзадач.
 Так, чтобы всегда ссылался на текущий массив отображаемых задач. */

Comment: @Cipher Когда в переменную присваивают массив или объект, он полностью не копируется туда. Переменная хранит только ссылку на массив. Кликнули, например, на первую задачу? Найти массив её подзадач и присвоить в переменную: `CURR_TASK_SPACE = itemsArray[0].sub;` А кликнули на "назад" ? - хочется выйти ко всем задачам, вернуть `CURR_TASK_SPACE = itemsArray;` А вот вставку таблицы, добавлениие / удаление задач можно везде привязать к `CURR_TASK_SPACE` - т.е. нужно просто при кликах организвать присваивание нужного массива, с которым следует работать, в переменную.

Comment: @Cipher Т.е. в предложенном варианте в таблице нигде не будут физически хранится все подзадачи. Она будет отображать только список текущих задач или подзадач. А при переходе к подзадачам или основным задачам - обновлять значение `CURR_TASK_SPACE` при необходимости, и полностью обновить все внутренности tbody - в зависимости от массива, на который указывает переменная.

Comment: Прочитав все что Вы написали, картина в голове вроде сложилась. Но, затруднение с реализацией. Успешно удалось реализовать последнее (удаление,редакцию...) , с удаление небольшие проблемы , но это мелочь.
Начал все перекапывать и возникла проблема с реализацией . Ваш подсказки и код , понимаю куда поставить , но как его связать.Нужна помощь ♥
[ссылка](https://codepen.io/kirill_code/pen/oNxKMbq)

Comment: @ OPTIMUS PRIME , буду премного благодарен ♥. Постараюсь тоже что-то да додумать(придумать).

Comment: @Cipher Добавлен вариант в конце ответа*

Comment: @ OPTIMUS PRIME , за пример большое спасибо ♥ Утром сяду разбирать код.